# Clipper circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

If I want a clipper circuit that clips at the negative voltage at -4 V, can both of the following solutions be used?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwY1XJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or is one more optimal than the other?

Comment: Do you want to clip everything above -4V? Because that's what the first circuit does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a simulation directly in Circuit Lab. I don't think that Circuit 1 does what you need, as it will clip everything above -4 V, as shown below:

[image]

Circuit 2 works as expected (clips anything *below* -4V):

[image]

Comment: I see. So the second case is the more apt. Can you also provide a description of how to correctly figure out how to set up a clipper circuit given conditions?

Comment: @JonathanSmit Can you clarify what you mean? What conditions?

Comment: Let's say I'm told to make a circuit that wants to clip the circuit at Vx and Vy. How do I systematically go about doing this? I always seem to get the DC voltages and diodes in the wrong direction. My solution was the first circuit I made. The real solution is the one on the right. So I wanted some help regarding this.

Comment: @JonathanSmit You need to consider how a diode is biased during each cycle. In the first circuit, the diode is forward biased, so it will conduct when the wave is positive. In the second circuit, the diode is reversed, so it will only conduct when the wave is negative. I could try and explain it in detail, but I don't think I could do a better job than this website: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode-clipping-circuits.html